# Is TA-lib.org support on iOS on iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

I would like to add Technical analysis support to my financial project on iphone. And I found TA-lib on www.ta-lib.org, this library supports many indicators I need.

I would like to ask: Can I use ta-lib on my iphone development? And how I can do it, because this library is written in C language? I knew that Cocoa can compile C but how I can do it, import this library to iOS?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone answer my question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone SDK tools will compile most portable C code just fine (C is a pure subset of Objective C).  There appears to be C source code available for the library in which you're interested.  If so, you could try just including the source to the library in your iPhone Xcode project, and see if it all compiles, which it might if there are no dependency or collision problems.  You may or may not need the entire library, which might help simplify things (or not).

You could also compile a separate static library, and then include that library, and the headers, in your iPhone app; but that technique may be a bit more complicated that your requirements might indicate.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I am looking for. Actually I am doing with the second situation, compiling a static library and import it to my project. Many thanks to your response.

Comment: am trying to add the static library, but it throws linker error. any suggestions as how to add it properly? thanks